# consider only first hierarchy cluster matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, hierarchy, linkage

I'm using the function linkage in matlab.
How can I plot only the first hierarchy?

```
DSIM_vec = [0.2428    0.0829    0.1008    0.2348    0.1681    0.0982]
Z = linkage (DSIM_vec,'average')

% In this case cluster [1 3] shouldn't be grouped with the element 4.
dendrogram(Z)


T = cluster(Z,....);
```

I would like that T contains only the first hierarchyclusters...
`T = [2 1 2 3]` would be the correct answer

Comment: What do you mean by first "hierarchy"?

Comment: I mean that clusters created at the first node shouldn't be clustered with other clusters/elements

Comment: I have also edited the question...I hope it s more clear...in short I don't want a hierarchycal clustering